# Is there any acid or base which has a pH value under 0 and over 14?

Tags: acid-base

what is the range of strong acid and base in pH scale.I have much confusion.

Comment: Please be more specific and do some research next time.

Comment: The known pH range goes from [-28](https://edu.rsc.org/everyday-chemistry/whats-the-strongest-acid-in-the-world/4014526.article) to [+22](https://qr.ae/prcsJ8).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution with **lowest pH value** (to the left of pH scale) will be the *strongest acid* while the solution with **highest pH value** (to the right of pH scale) will be the *strongest base*.

In technical words, the acid which dissociates completely into H+ ions in water will have the lowest pH value, while the base dissociates completely into OH- ions in water will have the highest pH value.

**EDIT :** Strongest acid has pH of 1 while strongest base has pH of 14.
(0 - 6.99 are acids. 7 is neutral. 7.1 - 14 are bases.)

I hope that helps.

Comment: It can actually go between -3 and 16. But for most acids and bases you deal with, they will be in the range of 1-14. There are different variables you can adjust, ie temperature, etc, but it's no longer a useful measure.

Comment: @Jun-GooKwak They can go beyond the limits of pH scale?

Comment: @hardik See http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed083p1465

Comment: @Jun-GooKwak Wow, thanks for adding that to my knowledge. :)

Comment: [Pure sulfuric acid has pH -12.](https://edu.rsc.org/everyday-chemistry/whats-the-strongest-acid-in-the-world/4014526.article#:~:text=For%20instance%2C%20hydrochloric%20acid%20comes,'%20acid%20you'll%20find.)

Answer (score 3):

Usually the range of a $pH$ scale is $0-14$. A higher number on the $pH$ scale means that the substance is **Basic**, a lower number means it is **Acidic**.

Another thought to keep in mind is that there can be a $pH$ less than $0$ and greater than $14$. But let's not get into that right now. The pH scale was made for our convenience and cannot be a totally accurate representation of the real world.

**Have you done some research on this? Be more specific in what you do not understand.**

Possible duplicates:

1. [What is the difference between the titration of a strong acid with a strong base and that of the titration of a weak acid with a strong base?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4081/what-is-the-difference-between-the-titration-of-a-strong-acid-with-a-strong-base?rq=1)
2. [Why do strong acids have weak conjugate bases?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10650/why-do-strong-acids-have-weak-conjugate-bases?rq=1)
3. [What is a strong base?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24193/what-is-a-strong-base?rq=1)

Check [this](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed083p1465) out for more information.